# (Number(value) !== NaN) always true

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, numbers

I am using typescript for the first time, and I face a quite strange problem.

I am trying to make calculation like a calculator, so when a user press a button it could be a digit, 2 3 4 ... or an operation * \ + ...

On button press, I call a function, and the function check if it is a digit, or an operation in order to call the adequate function.

I compare my string like this :

```
if (Number(value) !== NaN) {
  // it is a number
} else {
  // it is an operation
}
```

although this work in the console ( by that I mean I do have a digit (3,4,5) when I press a number and NaN when I press an operation) this line ALWAYS return true, so I always consider it a number.

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261938/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-nan-and-nan-nan

Comment: `NaN === NaN` is `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check is value is NaN or not you should use `isNaN` function.

```
if(isNaN(value)) {
  //do this if NaN
} else {
  //do this if not
}
```

BTW: On **SO** a lot of similar questions ;) eg: [How do you test for NaN in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript)

Comment: thougt typescript would have a different function

Comment: "*BTW: On SO a lot of similar questions*" - please flag to close as a duplicate, then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isNaN(value)`. It returns true if `value` is a number and False otherwise.